# how to get value of a model instance at specified time in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a point awarding method in my website and I want to create a "top users in last 10 days" list. right now I store and update user scores in Profile model which is:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

but I want to get the value of this "point" instance at for example 10 days ago for comparing it to latest value. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is, in general, no way to inspect the previous values of a database field. AWS RDS has some features that come close to this, but they are for disaster recovery/forensics purposes, and not practical for frequent use.

That means you'll have to store the historical data somewhere yourself.

One simple way would be to pick a cutoff time, maybe every day for instance, and record each score at that time. There are a number of reasonable designs for this depending on your needs – one very simple one would be to add a single field to the Profile that stores a JSON list of the user's scores at the cutoff time for the last 10 days. Then schedule a job that runs at the cutoff time, adds the current score to the list, and removes the oldest one.

A more robust and expensive solution would be to track every point change. Make a new table with the schema (ProfileId, PointChange, Date) and add a row every time anyone gains or loses a point. With the entire history stored, you can build a query that can answer any possible question about prior state. You'd probably want to run a cleanup job that deletes data whose Date is sufficiently old, because this table will probably grow very quickly.

Comment: thanks for the answer. since I'm new to django can you add a practical code for your json suggested way?

Comment: Don't have time right now to write the whole thing up, but you'll want to look into Django management commands, and schedule one with cron. There are some JSONField extensions to Django, but you don't need one - you can just use a CharField and parse the JSON with python's json library. The actual logic is simple, just parse the list, append the new value, pop off the first value, convert it back to JSON and write it to db.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [django-simple-history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history). This app automatically stores historical data for tables that you specify in a separate table.

You would add a `HistoricalRecords` field to your model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

You can then query history as of a specific timestamp like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

hist_profile = profile.history.as_of(datetime(2018, 01, 01, 12, 0, 0))
```